# Get InnertText from input with pupperteer-sharp using C# and XPath

Tags: xpath, innertext, puppeteer-sharp

How to get the innerText from a `<input>` using XPath?

I have this to work but with CSS, but it do not work for me with XPath

```
    IElementHandle ha = await page.QuerySelectorAsync(xpath);
    IJSHandle ith = await ha.GetPropertyAsync("value");
    string val = ith.RemoteObject.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: `input` elements are empty elements so what kind of "inner text" do you expect to find for an `input` element?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
using PuppeteerSharp;

using var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync();
await using var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions { Headless = true });

using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
{
    await page.GoToAsync("http://www.google.de/");
    var input = (await page.XPathAsync("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/center/input[1]"))[0];
    var ith = await input.GetPropertyAsync("value");
    var val = ith.RemoteObject.Value.ToString();
    Console.Write(val);
}
```